# How to calculate difference of current year and birth year

Tags: java

I have a project in my programming class where I have to find the age of someone by taking the current year and subtracting their birth year. However, when I wrote the code, it keeps giving me the answer of "50.0minus50.0=0.0".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ageMath {
    String firstName;
    static int currentYear;
    static int birthYear;
    double mathEquation;'

    Scanner lookAtKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void getFirstName() {
        System.out.println("What is your first name");
        firstName = lookAtKeyboard.nextLine();
    }

    public void getCurrentYear() {
        System.out.println("What is the current year");
        currentYear = lookAtKeyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
    }

    public void getBirthYear() {
        System.out.println("What is your birth year");
        birthYear = lookAtKeyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
    }

    public void doMath(double birthYear, double currentYear) {
        mathEquation = currentYear - birthYear;
        System.out.println(currentYear +"minus"+ birthYear + "=" + mathEquation);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ageMath calculator = new ageMath();
        calculator.getFirstName();
        calculator.getCurrentYear();
        calculator.getBirthYear();
        calculator.doMath(currentYear,birthYear);
    }
}
```

What should I do in order to fix this?

Comment: What inputs are you giving your code to cause this output? Be specific about what causes the problem.

Comment: `charAt(0)` gives you the integer representation of the first character in that String (50 for the character `2`). You want `Integer.parseInt(lookAtKeyboard.nextLine());` or `lookAtKeyboard.nextInt();`

Comment: I'm tryin to make the inputs be the user-defined birth & current year.

Comment: switch the parameters when you call `doMath`, otherwise you will always get negative ages. It should be `calculator.doMatch(birthYear,currentYear)`

Comment: Right, but what inputs did you use to get the output "50.0minus50.0=0.0"?

Answer (score 3):

For int you have to use `nextInt()`.The `java string charAt()` method returns a `char value` at the given index number.Which is not suitable for the current scenario of yours.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {




String firstName;

static int currentYear;

static int birthYear;

double mathEquation;

Scanner lookAtKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


public void getFirstName()
{
System.out.println("What is your first name");
firstName =lookAtKeyboard.nextLine();
}

public  void getCurrentYear() {
System.out.println("What is the current year");
currentYear =lookAtKeyboard.nextInt();
}

public  void getBirthYear() {
System.out.println("What is your birth year");
birthYear =lookAtKeyboard.nextInt();
}

public void doMath(double birthYear, double currentYear) {
mathEquation = currentYear - birthYear;
System.out.println(currentYear +"minus"+ birthYear + "=" +mathEquation);

}



public static void main (String[] args) {

Main calculator = new Main();
calculator.getFirstName();
calculator.getCurrentYear();
calculator.getBirthYear();
calculator.doMath( currentYear,birthYear);

}


}
```

Working [link](https://repl.it/repls/EssentialRemoteScriptinglanguages) (I just changed the class name ,so that it can work on fiddle)

Answer (score 1):

`char(0)` returns the ascii value of '2' as you have probably entered `2019` as current year.

See [ASCII tabel](http://www.asciitabel.be/)

If you want the same input behaviour (user presses enter after each input) you can read the input as string and parse it to an int:

```
public void getCurrentYear() {
    System.out.println("What is the current year");
    currentYear = Integer.parseInt(lookAtKeyboard.nextLine());
}

public void getBirthYear() {
    System.out.println("What is your birth year");
    birthYear = Integer.parseInt(lookAtKeyboard.nextLine());
}
```

(please also look at my comment regarding the order of parameters when calling doMath in the main method.